# How to address a letter to a Ph.D.?

Tags: letter-writing

I'd like to write a letter to someone that has a Ph.D.
What is the most correct way of addressing to that person?
- Dear Mr. [Name]
- Dear Mr. [Name], Ph.D.,
- ...something else...

Comment: Dear Dr. _____ (as should be obvious)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Dear Doctor [Name]

http://www.formsofaddress.info/Professor.html

http://www.formsofaddress.info/PA.html#PA006

Where appropriate:

Dear Professor [Name]